# Android , Widget, Change Screen , Method called

Tags: android, widget

When i drag an app widget from one screen to the next,
which is the method that will be called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method called on your `AppWidgetProvider` if the user elects to move or resize it on the home screen.

Note that not all home screens have the notion of "drag an app widget from one screen to the next".

Comment: When i set a frame animation on a xml and when i set it to an image view, and when  i drag the widget to next screen, the animation begins to play . How can you explain this behavior ?

Comment: @Achilles: If you did not want the animation to play, you should not have added the animation. Rendering the app widget's `ViewGroup` is the responsibility of the home screen, not you. The home screen is welcome to do whatever it wants, and what any given home screen does will, in part, be decided by the author of that home screen.

Comment: Commonsware, Do you mean to say that the widgets are actually rendered by the homescreen ? I mean , when the widget is updated using the appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget() , the homescreen does the job of reflecting the change of the widget on the screen ?

Comment: @Achilles: "Do you mean to say that the widgets are actually rendered by the homescreen ?" -- yes.

Comment: CommonsWare : Is it like , when the widget is updated , some signal is sent to the homescreen to render the widget again ? And where do i look into the code if i want to know how exactly are the widgets getting drawn ?

Comment: @Achilles: "Is it like , when the widget is updated , some signal is sent to the homescreen to render the widget again ?" -- yes. "And where do i look into the code if i want to know how exactly are the widgets getting drawn ?" -- I would start with `AppWidgetManager`.